# What is the difference of "z" and "Z" when closing an SVG path?

Tags: svg

When creating an SVG path, typically the capital letters (`M`, `L`...) in the [`d` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) refer to absolute coordinates and the lower case letters (`m`, `l`...) refer to relative coordinates to the last point.

Here's an example that draws a small right triangle in absolute coordinates:

```
<path style="stroke:black;fill:none;" d="M100,100 L150,100 V50 Z" />
```

This draws the same triangle in relative coordinates:

```
<path style="stroke:black;fill:none;" d="m100,100 l50,0 v-50 z" />
```

I can use a capital or lowercase `M` and `Z` in either case and visually, nothing is changed. Regarding `M`, I assume that since it is the first point, it is absolute or relative to (0, 0), but please correct me if that is wrong. What is the difference of `z` and `Z`?

Comment: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ is a great online tool to play with d-paths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases:

> An upper-case command specifies absolute coordinates, while a lower-case command specifies coordinates relative to the current position. [path_commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#path_commands)

But in the case of z/Z, there is no difference ([ClosePath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#closepath)). There is no absolute or relative coordinate associated with the z/Z, so it will just create a straight line between the last point and the starting point.

Answer (score 4):

##### Both `z` and `Z` define the [Path Command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#path_commands): **`ClosePath`**

---

> Path commands are instructions that define a path to be drawn. Each command is composed of a command letter and numbers that represent the command parameters.
>
> SVG defines 6 types of path commands, for a total of 20 commands:
>
> - MoveTo: `M`, `m`
> - LineTo: `L`, `l`, `H`, `h`, `V`, `v`
> - Cubic Bézier Curve: `C`, `c`, `S`, `s`
> - Quadratic Bézier Curve: `Q`, `q`, `T`, `t`
> - Elliptical Arc Curve: `A`, `a`
> - **ClosePath**: `Z`, `z`